# extract and store in session then redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to take a querystring from a submitted url, store it in a session variable and then redirect to another php page prior to starting php?

I am looking for a solution in .htaccess (Mod-rewrite).

User enters url
 /home.php?id=fred

then in .htaccess the id=fred is stripped off and placed in $_SESSION['id'] = 'fred'
 and **before** being sent to /index.php

I have tried to use the following in PHP but this seems to fail

## home.php

```
<?php
$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($qs, $gets);
// there are reasons for not just moving the $_GET values direct to $_SESSION
sanitise_gets($gets); // filters the values for valid values into $_SESSION

// redirect user to real 'home' page
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/index.php';
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Location: ".$url,true,303);
exit();

function sanitise_gets((array) $gets) {
...
}
?>
```

Another problem is that the redirection inside PHP seems to just show index.php/?id=fred !
It should NEVER be possible for the user to bookmark or go back to home.php

I guess the question really boils down to:
**Can you write to a session cookie in .htacces?**

Comment: Using Occam's Razor philosophy, why are you trying to do it? Seems a lot of trouble for little reasons, may there be a simpler way.

Comment: id=sensitive information<br />

Comment: @Aedix Rhinedale besides I have never subscribed to Occam's (or anyone's) philosophy that dictates to others what should be done. I am more interested in finding a solution to a problem.

Comment: I was just asking more scenario details (without sensitive info) to try to abstract your problems in a simpler way, so you could solve it quicker. That's the philosophy, *the simpler way tends to be the better one* . But never mind.

Comment: @Aedix Rhinedale Sorry but it didn't come across that way... more like why bother. For me the simple solution would be one or two lines of code in  .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

After going bald!
I think I have a workaround - never perfect, but does what I need - eliminating that querystring from the address bar!

**home.php** (new and simple)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['q_s'])) { unset($_SESSION['q_s']); }
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
    $_SESSION['q_s'] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
}
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Location: index.php?',true,301);
?>
```

The important points seem to be to prevent caching and that '?' after index.php in the redirection url. The point being to store the querystring in the session, so we must remember to start the session!

**.htaccess** (now becomes)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule index.php(.*) /index.php? [L,R=301]
```

Obviously all calls to index.php must be with POST data and never GET data so all references to index on the site that involve links need to be replaced (in our case there are none) with home.php?whatever

The $_SESSION['q_s'] can be dealt with inside index.php in the usual way.

Users who use browser plugins to convert POSTs to GETs will be treated as if they are abusing the site and will be left with the vanilla index page as their query strings will be lost.

I have left off the sanitise_gets() function for clarity but it is important to sanitise the QUERY_STRING before using it, probably before even saving it to the session.